# What does x.length do in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, math

I am doing this JavaScript math question where it asks me his math question. I do the math, type the answer in the box, and sumbit it. If i am right I move on but I got lost at x.length.  I don't know what that means.  Here is a example of the problem:

```
var a= 5+6*4
var b= a / 9
Function (x)
(
        if (x.length == b)
```

Comment: You have a broken code fragment here. Your "x" is a function parameter that is either a string or an array (both of which have a .length property), but without the rest that comes after the "if" statement, there's no telling what it does.

Comment: Also, you need to learn the difference between Function and function. I suspect you don't really mean Function here.

Comment: I've cleaned this up (with help from tvanfosson) as much as I can, but I don't know what the orignal code is (and the code you've posted is broken).  Christopher Richa has a reasonably good guess about what you're looking for, but if that doesn't hit the spot, you will be more likely to get helpful responses if you can fix the code sample.

Answer (score 1):

This is what he is after... most likely..

```
var foo = 5 + 6 * 7 
var bar = foo % 8
var moo = bar * 2
var rar = moo / 3
function check(x)
{
        if (x.length == moo)
        {
                        alert("win!");
                        window.location += "?lvl_password="+x;
        } else {
                        alert("fail D:");
     }
}
```

It's a mission in hackthissite.org to break a javascript password login

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Robusto: this is a broken code. However, x.length can mean one of three things:

- the number of items in an array;
- the number of characters in a String;
- the number of digits in an integer;

and more.